# How to make a custom tile in Windows 8 from an old program?

Tags: windows-8

I've got an old Visual Studio 6-made program, and when I install it on Windows 8, it has a default tile. Problem is, it's the smaller tile and the name of the program is too long to fit in comfortably, plus the icon is resized and looks bad.

Is there a way to create a custom Windows 8 tile that's got a different size and icon, without actually creating a specific Windows 8 program? I'd like to be able to do this with batch files as well if possible.

Comment: In RTM, the desktop tiles have changed: the icons are larger, and the label text is the same size and in the same position as on metro tiles. Check a Surface demo video for proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro apps in Windows 8 have the full experience of creating live tiles, secondary tiles, wide tiles, etc.  Only Metro apps can customize their tiles, not desktop apps.  The tile APIs exist only in WinRT for Metro apps.

For a desktop app like you have (the "old Visual Studio 6-made program" that is not Metro), you can try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144119(v=vs.85).aspx.  Make sure to click on the other topics in the left sidebar too.

Edit:
This method can change the icon for older applications.  Since the icon is what is used in the start menu, this is a way to give older apps a more attractive static icon in the new start menu.

Comment: Thanks, but that's for the Icon - I'm looking for information on Tiles. There must be a way of manually constructing the Tile info without being a Metro app.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that isn't possible.  Only Metro apps can customize their tiles, not desktop apps.  I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, maybe I'll try making a launcher Metro app. Does anyone know if something like that exists already?

Comment: while this was an accepted answer, I consider it wrong. This directs the user to documentation on manipulating (setting/changing) icons as they appear in tiles, and now how to create a tile.

Comment: @robertotomás The answer states that you cannot create a live-tile for a non-metro application.  The second part indicates how you can get a static icon for an _existing application_.  Since an app's icon is how it shows up in the new start menu, that is an appropriate way to give an older application a good static start menu icon.

Comment: Bummer, so Windows shows the default desktop icon in the tile and there's no way to embed an alternative icon for display on the Desktop? Analogous to having a 32x32 and 16x16 icon and Windows choosing the appropriate one, we can't simply include a 80x80 (or whatever the tile badge dimensions are)? Unfortunate. Now legacy apps will all need to have a Metro launcher to look nice on the "Tiletop".

Comment: PS: We're not looking to create a live tile with Metro functionality. We just want to use a higher-resolution icon for the tile _image_. Clearly this is possible using a program such as Modern Tile Maker (http://www.thewindowsclub.com/modern-tile-maker-windows-8) or OblyTile (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865). So the question is, how do we with legacy apps to deploy create the .LNK shortcut specifying a tile image programatically or via an install script/property? Those programs are doing it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst live tiles are not supported for desktop applciations in Windows 8, you can improve the appearence of the icons by ensuring your Icon resource has [sizes for 48px, 64px, 96px and 128px](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To create the tile, right click on the executable (.exe, .com, .bat, etc), then left click on "Pin to Start".

To resize the tile, right click on the tile and select the size you want.

To move the tile, drag and drop to where you want it.

If you want to change the name, make a shortcut, change the shortcut name to what you want, then pin that to start.